# user. and number later

Tags: javascript, discord.js

i have a one field that after the `user.` starts with a number, which ends up giving a `missing ) after argument list`, how could I solve this?
I can't change it because I'm getting `3v3Victories` from an api

`.addField("Wins 3v3", user.3vs3Victories, true)`

Comment: You have to use `[]` notation for key names that start with numbers ... `user['3vs3Victories']`

Comment: @charlietfl it is returning 'undefined'

Comment: You will need to provide a [mre] that demonstrates it then. As noted in the duplicate chain this is the only way to work with keys that start with numbers die to js engines expect a dot before a number to be a decimal